# Why Extra Copy in List<T>.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, generics, generic-list

I'm looking at the open source code for [System.Collections.Generic.List<T>](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,245).  The `AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` method looks like this:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection) {
     Contract.Ensures(Count >= Contract.OldValue(Count));
 
     InsertRange(_size, collection);
}
```

and the `InsertRange(int, IEnumerable<T>)` methods looks like this:

```
public void InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection) {
    if (collection==null) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.collection);
    }
        
    if ((uint)index > (uint)_size) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument.index, ExceptionResource.ArgumentOutOfRange_Index);
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    ICollection<T> c = collection as ICollection<T>;
    if( c != null ) {
        int count = c.Count;
        if (count > 0) {
            EnsureCapacity(_size + count);
            if (index < _size) {
                Array.Copy(_items, index, _items, index + count, _size - index);
            }
                
            if (this == c) {
                Array.Copy(_items, 0, _items, index, index);
                Array.Copy(_items, index+count, _items, index*2, _size-index);
            }
            else {
                T[] itemsToInsert = new T[count];        // WHY?
                c.CopyTo(itemsToInsert, 0);              // WHY?
                itemsToInsert.CopyTo(_items, index);     // WHY?

                // c.CopyTo(_items, index);              // WHY NOT THIS INSTEAD???
            }
            _size += count;
        }             
    }
    else {
        using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
            while(en.MoveNext()) {
                Insert(index++, en.Current);                                    
            }                
        }
    }
    _version++;            
}
```

Assume we make a call like this:

```
var list1 = new List<int> {0, 1, 2, 3};
var list2 = new List<int> {4, 5, 6, 7};
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

When this hits `InsertRange(int, IEnumerable<T>)` internally, it ultimately hits the else condition highlighted by `// WHY?` comments.

Why is an array allocated, elements from `list2` are copied into that temporary array, and then the elements are copied from that temporary array to the end of `list1`?  Why the extra copy?  Why not just copy the elements straight from `list2` to the end of `list1` using the `ICollection<T>.CopyTo()` method?

---

#### EDIT

I would respectfully submit that while the question is subject to speculation by those of us who did not write the code to begin with, there nevertheless **is** an answer to the question.  There is a reason the code was written the way it was, and my hope was that someone with that knowledge might provide an explanation, even if only for historical purposes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188912/discussion-on-question-by-matt-davis-why-extra-copy-in-listt-addrangeienumera).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments section by @OlivierJacot-Descombes, the extra copy in question has been removed in the current version of [List.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs#L740) in the .NET Core Libraries (CoreFX) and replaced by the single copy version, i.e., `c.CopyTo(_items, index);`.

Thanks to @elgonzo and @IvanStoev for providing thought-provoking comments.  Summing things up, it may be that this is simply an artifact of the evolution of `List<T>` and represents the best option at the time it was developed, but that is just a guess.